# Changing scientific notation to Zero in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet which when refreshed comes up with scientific notation rather than zero e.g. 2.3283064365387E-10.  The data comes from an external system and I can't control the output of that system.

It does display correctly as zero but when I use this data to calculate percentages it comes up with a random %.  I can go in an manually change them to zero but was wondering if there was a better way of doing this.

Comment: "when I use this data to calculate percentages it comes up with a random %" ... that is a little surprising. Excel shouldn't treat a very small double-precision number differently than any other. Is the value actually a number, or perhaps a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the formula that references the cell to calculate percentages, use the Round function to round these numbers to 0, keeping the required level of precision on cells with legitimate numbers.

E.g. If your current formula is referencing the problem value in cell A1 as:

```
=A1/B1
```

Modify it to:

```
=Round(A1,8)/B1
```

This will still keep 8 decimal places of precision on legitimate number, but will change numbers with exponents less than -8 to exactly 0.

Comment: There is no formula its just a result from a system that produces the report.  If that makes any sense.

Comment: You said you were using the data to calculate percentages. Where and how are you doing that calculation? Changing that calculation is easier than changing these values to zero.

Comment: I am with you now.  There are a lot of formulas.  I am going to use your version and change them as I find them, so going forwards they will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CCur` in your calculations if no more than four decimals:

```
? CCur(2.3283064365387E-10)
 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 to actually change the values to zero:

Insert an adjacent column to round the numbers:

```
=Round(A1,8)
```

Then use this column for any subsequent calculations. Or, you can copy and paste-as-values to convert the formulas to values then delete the original column.

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 to actually change the value to zero:

If the number format used is displaying these values as 0 in Excel, then you can use an advanced setting to force the value of all cells in the workbook to match exactly the way they look on screen.

File > Options > Advanced > When calculating this workbook > Set precision as displayed

[image]

Note that this is a dangerous setting that will impact your entire workbook. All data will be truncated to match how it is displayed, which will remove accuracy on all decimal numbers. Only use it if the resulting accuracy is sufficient on all number.

Comment: That is a great solution but as you say will possibly impact the whole workbook and any other sheets I am using. Thanks for the idea though.